Modify ScriptableObject through editor script
I have TranslationData : ScriptableObject that stores all translations and custom inspector view for TranslatableText

There from this custom inspector view i should modify linked TranslationData, but i can't resave this asset.
I try this (look like a bad practice):
EditorUtility.SetDirty(translationData);
// Modifying value of ScriptableObject asset
translationData.data[textField.value] = new TranslationData.Node();
// Saving (i think)
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();

And this works for recompiles, but not for restarting unity or building app
Is there any way to update SerializedProperty.objectReferenceValue and save it?

...presumably there's a file-path you can specify that will make it save data outside your ephemeral bin directory?

The problem was using Dictionary, unity didn't serialize field with that type.
EDIT:
So unity can't serialize Dictionary (like almost any generic non-primitive types).
There 2 tricks to make Dictionary serializable:

Copy all keys and values into custom List<TKey> keys and List<TValue> values before serialization with ISerializationCallbackReceiver

public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<TKey> keys = new();
    [SerializeField]
    public List<TValue> values = new();
    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        keys = Keys.ToList();
        values = Values.ToList();
    }
    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        Clear();
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
            Add(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
}


Create a non-generic type, because Unity serializer can't handle generics for some reason:

// Node type also Serializable
[Serializable]
public class SDictionaryOfStringAndNode : SerializableDictionary<string, Node> { };
[SerializeField]
public SDictionaryOfStringAndNode data = new();

Be cereful with recursive serialization! max recursion depth that unity can handle is 10, so any tree-structures better to serialize without any recursion (by creating {path: object, ..} dict inside OnBeforeSerialize for example)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
